# Why do Worf and Geordie have different ranking pips when they’re both Lieutenants?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *The Child* (Season 2), Worf is called "lieutenant" and so is Geordie, but they have different pips (one has 1 full and 1 half pip, and the other 2).  Why is this so?

Comment: This may help: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/are-the-star-trek-next-generation-rank-pips-based-on-anything-from-real-life/2215

Comment: Just as a note, the water based services (Navy, Coast Guard) are the only ones to use this ranking system. For other military (At least in the US) 2nd Lieutenant = Ensign, 1st Lt = Lt Jr Grade, Captain = Lt, Major = Lt. Commander, Lt. Colonel = Commander, and Colonel = Captain.

Comment: @WadCheber testing, testing 123

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is that there are three forms of lieutenant - lieutenant *junior grade*, lieutenant and lieutenant commander (see images below).  In this episode, Worf is Lieutenant (Junior grade) and Geordie is a full Lieutenant.  An example of the Lieutenant commander rank is Data.  For further reference, see [this](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_ranks) page.

[image: Lieutenant (junior grade)]
Lieutenant (junior grade)

[image: Lieutenant]
Lieutenant

[image: Lieutenant Commander]
Lieutenant Commander

Comment: For the non-military among us, a Lieutenant Commander is never referred to as a Lieutenant, he is referred to (in order to flatter him, or as a sign of respect) as Commander, which is his next official rank upgrade.

Comment: @Thaddeus I doubt that very much. The "main rank" is given by the number of
pips. If one has a dark part (half-pip), that means he is junior in
that rank. However, for higher ranks, you will not tell people they
are junior. Hence the word "Lieutenant" is used instead of "junior",
and it originally means "can take the role of". Hence, as a Junior
Lieutenant is a Lieutenant, a Lieutenant Commander is a Commander, and
a Lieutenant Colonel is a Colonel as far as responsibilities are
concerned. No flattery or special respect there.

Comment: @babou - I agree with most of your assertion, but Lt Col and Col have very different responsibilities. Ranks are elevated as a courtesy in most situations. The more formal the situation, the more likely it is that the full rank will be used.

Comment: @JohnP Agreed. In practice, junior people usually have different
responsabilities as they are trained for the new rank. However, in
principle, they can hold the place ("tenir lieu" in French) of the
full rank officier. There is also probably a historical side to it.

Comment: @babou - There is, and a lot of it goes back to castle days, which is beyond the scope here, but as an aside, it explains why a Lieutenant General is a higher rank than a Major General, etc.

Comment: @JohnP The original rank in the German General Staff was Sergeant-Major General

Comment: Litutenant Commander was, in the US, originally Lieutenant-Commandant, wore a lieutenant's uniform, not the distinctive uniform of a Master & Commander (which was later shortened to Commander), and both Lieutenant-Commandant and Master & Commander promoted to captain. So stating Lieutenant Commander as a form of lieutenant isn't actually wrong, but it's certainly an archaism.

Comment: Babou, as a former member of the United States military, I can attest to the form of address used in the modern Navy as both proper and accurate as I have described it. In previous eras, a Lieutenant might have encompassed some different paradigm but today, A junior lieutenant, a lieutenant and a Lieutenant Commander were three distinctly different ranks, with different protocols of address for all three. A junior lieutenant, a "Luey" (a full lieutenant) and a "Commander" were each afforded a different level of respect and allocation of manpower and resources.